# Proper expression of past and future tense

Tags: translation

Saluton,
Mi volas scii se ĉi tiun frazon estas korekta traduko.

"They already asked me, if I will go to the beach."

"Ili jam petis min, de mi iros al la strando."

Mi estas instruita per poŝtelefono Duolingo, kaj ne povas memori la korekta rimedo por pluraj gramatikoj.

Comment: I strongly suggest using a web browser for your first Duolingo run, because the browser version contains grammar lessons, which are missing in the phone versions.

Answer (score 2):

La angla frazo konsistas el du propozicioj: "They already asked me" kaj "if I will go to the beach". Ni pritaktu ilin.

**"They already asked me"**

Temas pri ricevi informon pri iu afero, do oni uzas la verbon ["demandi iun pri io"](http://vortaro.net/#demandi). Notu, ke oni forlasas la parton "pri io", kiam oni montras per subpropozicio la temon de la demando.

> Ili demandis min…

**"if I will go to the beach"**

La angla "if" havas plurajn sencojn kaj unu estas komenci demandan subpropozicion, same kiel "whether". Por demanda subpropozicio oni uzas en Esperanto la saman demandovorton kiel en ekvivalenta demando, alivorte "ĉu".

Kvankam oni demandis en pasinteco ("…demandis…"), la tempo por la ago "iri" dependas de tio, ĉu vi en la momento de la demando iras, vi estas survoje (elektu "iras") aŭ intencas poste iri, ankoraŭ ne estas survoje (elektu "iros"). Verŝajne temas pri la estonteco, do "iros" estas ĝusta. Jes, oni "iros al iu loko", sed oni kutime uzas la vorton "plaĝo" anstataŭ "strando". Mi pensas, ke ankaŭ Duolingo ekskluzive uzas "plaĝon".

Sume

> Ili jam demandis min, ĉu mi iros al la plaĝo.